# How to place content below a position absolute item without affect div changes

Tags: html, css

I have html div like

```
div A            

div B

Div D
div c
Div E
```

i want structure like

```
div A           Div C

div B           div D
Div E
```

i did for

```
.c {
    top: 0;
    right: 220px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

now div c is in top,Next i want Div D

```
.d {
top: 566px;
position: absolute;
right: 291px;
}
```

i can adjust this but problem is that when i extend content from Div c it will overlap to div D?How can i move Div D under Div C?please help

Here is my code

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h3>Our Team</h3>
    </li>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>d</li>
    <li style="top:20px; position:absolute; right:120px">e</li>
    <li style="top:20px; position:absolute; right:120px">f</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: i need a html code to fix this? share the code?

Comment: You can achieve this using `float` or `display: inline-block` or `flex`, why use position?

Comment: How has this question got two upvotes? *sigh* - can you add an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question so we've got something to work with?

Comment: @KareemDabbeet i have update my question

Comment: @Manikandan2811 i have update

Comment: @LintoThomas And I have answered the question :)

Comment: @LintoThomas You can check the answer to see if it provides the solution  for you

Comment: why you dont change the divs order in html?

Answer (score 3):

You Can use `CSS Grid` Instead:

[Complete Grid Guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

First Define your Grid Template Areas:

```
grid-template-areas: "i1 i3" ". ." "i2 i4" "i5 .";
grid-template-rows: repeat(4,1fr);
```

**grid-template-areas:** Defines a grid template by referencing the names of the grid areas which are specified with the grid-area property

each "" refer to row.

For example: first row have two columns:

1- `i1` takes 1 of 2  from the first row.

2- `i2` takes 1 of 2 from the first row.

**grid-template-rows: repeat(4,1fr)**: will make sure that all rows have same height (even empty ones).

To apply this area to div:

1- Define the div in html:

```
<div class="item i1">Div A</div>
```

2- add to css:

```
.i1 { grid-area: i1}
```

and so on.

Working Demo:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "i1 i3" ". ." "i2 i4" "i5 .";
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  margin: 25px;
}

.i1 {
  grid-area: i1
}

.i2 {
  grid-area: i2
}

.i3 {
  grid-area: i3
}

.i4 {
  grid-area: i4
}

.i5 {
  grid-area: i5
}

.item {
  min-height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item i1">Div A</div>
  <div class="item i2">Div B</div>
  <div class="item i3">Div C</div>
  <div class="item i4">Div D</div>
  <div class="item i5">Div E</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use columns are rows to create that layout

Demo:

```css
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="a">div a</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="c">div c</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="b">div b</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="d">div d</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="e">div e</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you're not having space between first and second row as requested in question

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS Grids if you just want to adjust the content
[Updated]I was warned that you want a specific position so I made the changes that can solve the problem

```css
main{max-width: 1170px; margin:0 auto; background:#f8f8f8; min-height:100vh;}

.grid-div div { border:1px solid #ccc;  background: #f0f0f0; min-height:150px; }

.grid-div {

  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap:20px;


} 

.a{grid-column: 1; grid-row: 1; }
.b{grid-column: 1; grid-row: 2;  margin-top:60px; }
.c{grid-column: 2; grid-row: 1; }
.d{grid-column: 2; grid-row: 2;  margin-top:60px; }
.e{grid-column: 1; grid-row: 3; }
.f{grid-column: 2; grid-row: 3; }
```

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Grid Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<main>
<div class="grid-div">
  
   <div class='a'>A</div>
   <div class='b'>B</div>
   <div class='c'>C</div>
   <div class='d'>D</div>
   <div class='e'>E</div>
   <div class='f'>F</div>


</div>
</main>
</body>
<html>
```

if you want to check more options to use in grid see here https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp

Comment: You're not positioning the element as required in question. this is not giving an answer.

Comment: Sorry for that was just a mistake reading the question A B "D C"  E,  and when I answered, he had not yet provided his complete code,  if was you that puted a negative mark it seems unfair because grids css was the right choice, the order is just a adjust that I happily could provide if you had not already done, so pls take of the negative mark

Comment: Edit your answer, maybe the one who voted down will remove it for the new edited answer

Comment: Make sense so I'll do that, tks for your feedback Kareem

Comment: Great, Last small thing, To make your code exactly the same with the question, there should be n empty row between a c and b d

Comment: Ho gosh, this questio was not really clear, I hope Linto Thomas can be more explainer in the futuro,  so I just put a margin-top in B and D to make a "gap", I think that is it what he wants, but if was a empty row that he wants, I'll wait for him to update this question, and be more explicit, tks again Kareen